# Python can't decode a character set

Tags: python, character-encoding

I've been using a program to process tick data. Recently it stopped working and crashed as soon as it starts processing the file. It seems that something has changed with how the vendor renders the data.

So let's say I simply run:

```
with open("N:\\2017\\2017-09-28 Daily.CAP") as f:
    i = 0
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/b.karjoo/Documents/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    c = f.read(1)
  File "C:\Users\b.karjoo\py3_virt_env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1799: character maps to <undefined>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will resolve the issue

```
  with open(filename, encoding="cp437") as file:
```

But if your file's encoding type is **not cp437 and something else apart from that** and if your using notepad++ to view your file, you can check its encoding type by clicking on

> Encoding, which will show the type of encoding.

If your using sublime text go to

> View -> Show Console
>
> Type into field at bottom view.encoding() and it will give you the encoding type.

Comment: I wasn't able to open the file with np++ because it says 20gb is too big. utf8 gives same error. So I started going through all the encoding options one by one. Finally I resorted to cp437 and I'm not getting the error. Not sure if the encoding is actually cp437, but it works.

Comment: so you made encoding="cp437" is it ?